# See what is changed before executing context.SaveChanges()

Tags: sql, entity-framework

In Entity Framework 5, Database-first, I am getting the error message

> error in saving entities which do not make foreign key properties available

when I am trying to save a single object .

I don't know if there is a problem with the definition and mappings of a field of my object, or if I have a wrong reference in there and the Framework is somehow expecting me to provide objects for the 0...N objects my object-to-save could be referencing.

How do I see what changes are going to be written? I used a library to show the SQL which is going to be sent to the database, but it seems like the error is thrown before EF tries to execute an SQL command.

Comment: you can debug with a breakpoint in `context.SaveChanges()` and check your objects being saved.

Comment: @Guillelon I have already done this, and the object looks perfectly good to me. Obviously the EF is expecting something I don't think is necessary. This is why I want to know what it is trying to save at all - is it just that one object, or is it trying to construct a whole object graph and finding null references (from a conceptual point of view, my information is in a valid state when there are null references, but maybe I messed up the implementation somewhere).